# After replacing default DI container Sitecore 8.2 Sitecore ItemService and EntityService stop working

Tags: dependency-injection, sitecore-services-client

Thanks to Dmytro Shevchenko
http://structuredcode.com/replacing-default-di-container-sitecore-8-2/

We are replacing default DI Container with Windsor Castle. All project works perfectly fine, except out of box Item Service and our custom Entity Service.

However it is registered fine to container.

Has anyone tried to replace DI container with any other and have same issue?
http://www.domain.com/sitecore/api/ssc/item/110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9?includeMetadata=true

Does this url work?

Thanks

Comment: What method did you use to replace it?

Comment: As Richard said it will likely depend on how you have registered your controller factory. Are you doing it in the Sitecore initialize pipeline or are you doing it within the global.asax or with WebActivator etc?

Comment: I have used siteocre intialize pipeline.

Comment: if you use `/sitecore/admin/ShowServicesConfig.aspx` can you see your services being registered ok?

Comment: I can see all sitecore services registered but not showing any custom registration for project.  we replaced MS DI with castle. Created windsor container in service builder pipeline and registered  sitecore services to windsor container.  Rest of project related di registration done at initialise pipelines.